# django.. select query

Tags: django

I want to search the male and female in my database and then display.

Actually my using radio button for male and female now i want when i select the male it will fetch all the male from database and then display and if select female vice-versa.

I don't konw how to use select query in django.

```
def search(request):
    search_gender = request.POST["gender"]

    if (search_gender == 'female'):
        Psear = PatientInfo.objects.get(gender__iexact='female')

        template = "../templates/admin/search.html"
        data = {'patientinfo_all': Psear,}
        return render_to_response( template, data, context_instance = RequestContext(request)
```

Comment: Why are you using `get`?  Shouldn't you be using `filter`?  Have you done the entire Django tutorial yet?  If you haven't done the whole tutorial, why not do that first and then revise your question.  Also, please use real words.  This isn't twitter.  Please spell words correctly.

Comment: My pet hate: the choices for 'gender' are not 'male' and 'female'. They are 'masculine' and 'feminine'. The category that contains 'male' and 'female' is 'sex'.

Answer (score 3):

get() method will return only one row, you are actually looking for filter():

```
Psear = PatientInfo.objects.filter(gender__iexact='female')
```